# How to return image URL as prefix https:// in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My django Rest API return image URL path http://blah/media/blah.jpg.
But I want to return https://blahblah.

Is there any attribute in settings.py?

```py
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

I Inserted this and tried

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

but it throws 301 code and nothing rendered.

Media setting

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: You can force a redirect to https in your HTTP server configuration. But also, how is your media url declared? See this link: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4294

Comment: I ran into the same problem, everything is normal, but the picture shows 404, the picture link returned by the API is: https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For serving media files there are two ways to do:

1. By serving media and static files using nginx, in that case you need
   to enable ssl in nginx and it will come as `https://`
2. by returning media file path from rest framework like `/media/image1.jpg` and adding your domain at client side like
   `https://mydomainxyz.com/media.image1.jpg`

When you activate `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` in django it redirects every request to https server. Django development server does not work on https. You will need nginx or apache server for that and enable ssl settings. This is the reason nothing is getting rendered. For more read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect) in django documentation